# How to ssh to Pre-built Snappy Ubuntu Core for BBB?

Tags: 14.04, ssh, 15.04, ubuntu-core, beagleboard

Following instructions on page - https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/snappy/start/#try-beaglebone - after I put SD card in with the pre-built snappy ubuntu core (ubuntu-15.04-snappy-armhf-bbb.img) and power on BBB, all 4 onboard LEDs (USR0 -> 3) are lit but do not flash and I'm unable to resolve host when attempting to connect from my laptop (Ubuntu 64-bit Desktop 14.04) via ssh ubuntu@webdm.local.

The BBB is connected via an ethernet cable directly to the home router and my ubuntu laptop connects via wifi.

Note: I've been ssh'ing successfully with same config but using an SD with Ubuntu 14.04 on BBB (http://www.armhf.com/boards/beaglebone-black/bbb-sd-install) but want to move across to Snappy now.

Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Update: plugged in monitor to Beaglebone Black and powered on. Same result and no signal went to the monitor. It freezes on boot up.

Answer (score 0):

Got the same issue you are experiencing. I have ordered a FTDI cable so I can actually debug from the serial console.

If you find a solution earlier let me know. Will update once I have some more debug info - as you are flying blind without the serial console access.

EDIT: This turned out to be a faulty image. I tried this again with downloading a new image and things are working fine now.

Also make sure that you press the "User Boot" button when turning on for at least 5 seconds as otherwise the BBB will boot into whatever OS is on the eMMC rather than the SD card.